# Pending transaction does not show on etherscan.io

Tags: wallets, etherscan

I had some ethereum on coinbase and I sent it to binance using the wallet address I got from there.  Even though it says pending in coinbase, it does not show up on etherscan.io.  Is that normal?  This is my first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd give it some time...and with the issues on the network now, like a few hours or so in time.  As long as it says pending on Coinbase, I wouldn't worry about it, but just sucks if you wanted the funds quickly.